# Can I install a swift without a keystone?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, keystone

I need only a swift object storage. Nothing more. All tutorials I have found use keystone when they install the swift storage. If I understood correctly keystone uses controller nodes. I ask this question because I have read that swift object storage can be installed independently. Please share any information how to install swift independently from other services. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift includes a [TempAuth](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_auth.html#tempauth) authentication mechanism that does not require Keystone.  It is often used for doing Swift development work.  The documentation includes an example of how to set this up:

- http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html